# Function implementation

Tags: c#, function, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class called Task which looks like this:

```
public class Task{
    List<Task> subTasks = new List<Task>();  
    public T executeTask<T>(){
        foreach(Task tsk in subTasks){
            tsk.executeTask();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have several other Tasks which inherit from the Task class like TaskA, TaskB and so on. They all should have their own implementation of executeTask.

The problem that I am facing is that some of the Tasks are doing calculations and some are performing string operations for example and return the result of the operation, which means the return type must be flexible or at least should not need a huge amount of casting.

Does anybody have a nice and clean idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Not a very brilliant idea to have a class named Task (and are you sure that you are not reinventing the wheel? [Class Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: In case you're not sure why Steve wrote his comment, here is a reference to a class playing central role in C#'s way of handling asynchronous execution: [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: No the name Task was just an example. It is actually another class with more stuff to it, which does not influence the problem

Comment: at which point does the amount of casting become huge for you?

Comment: when i use more casting than there are actual "Tasks"

Comment: To me this just seems like a `Func<T>`. It keeps an invocation list and can return a generic `T` return value.

Answer (score 0):

*..which means the return type must be flexible* - mean that inheritance will not help. With inheritance method "signature" should be same.

You can introduce general returned type and then use it for signature of your method.

```
public class Result
{
    public object Value {get; set;}
}

public interface IYourTask
{
    Result Execute();
}

public class StringManipulationTask
{
    public Result Execute()
    {
        // do something
        return new Result("resultofManipulation");
    }
}

public class NoReturnDataTask
{
    public Result Execute()
    {
        // do something
        return new Result(); // with no data - "empty result"
    }
}
```

Based on the behavior of the "result" you can introduce `Result` as abstraction and have own implementation for different behavior.

Summary - for using all tasks in same "general" way you should wrap all tasks in same format/signature.

Comment: Ok i forgot to say that some dont return a result, my bad.

Comment: @Curunir, in case when task doesn't return you can return "empty" result